# Select newest Telegram message with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, telegram

I want to code a bot which automatically selects the newest message send in a Telegram Group. This message should then be used as a link where to bot goes to.
So far I coded this but it looks like the newest message cannot be found with this class name.
I would appreciate any support!

```
while True:

    # Find newest message

    message = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME,value="text-content with-meta")

    # save message

    message_text = message.text

    # use as link
    link = message_text
    driver.get("https://key-drop.com/en/?code="+link)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I also tried to put all messages in a list but that does not seem to work either.
Edit: This is the html code for telegram message in a group:
[Foto of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCvHr.png)

I thought about using the xpath of the element which looks like this:

`//*[@id="message1650"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/text()`

Can I then  just tell the program to go to the newest xpath by adding a 1 to the message id in the xpath. like: `//*[@id="message1651"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/text()`
and if yes how do I do that?

Comment: _newest message cannot be found with this class name_: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: Are you not using the `python-telegram-bot` library? see https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot